# Issue with running .NET project with Docker (Visual Studio 2022)

Tags: .net, docker, visual-studio-2022

I have a problem running a project with Docker, I get the errors attached below in the console, it should be noted that this is a corporate computer, I found that there is an address from which a file is downloaded, do you think I should open the address and confirm the download? I see that it is a 403 status, so I wanted to make sure that it is a proxy at the following address:

https://vsdebugger.azureedge.net/

OR Full address with version:

https://vsdebugger.azureedge.net/vsdbg-17-2-10518-1/vsdbg-linux-x64.zip

```
C:\windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NonInteractive -NoProfile - 
WindowStyle Hidden -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -File 
"some\path\AppData\Local\Temp\GetVsDbg.ps1" -Version vs2017u5 -RuntimeID linux- 
musl-x64 -InstallPath "some\path\vsdbg\vs2017u5\linux-musl-x64"
Info: Using vsdbg version '17.2.10518.1'
Info: Using Runtime ID 'linux-musl-x64'
Info: Opening stream failed, trying again with proxy settings.
C:\Users\valeriroz\AppData\Local\Temp\GetVsDbg.ps1 : Exception calling "OpenRead" with 
"1" argument(s): "The remote 
server returned an error: (403) Forbidden."
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [GetVsDbg.ps1], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebException,GetVsDbg.ps1

A non-critical error occurred while getting the container(s) ready. Your project(s) will 
continue to function normally. The error was: The debugger path 
'some\path\vsdbg\vs2017u5' for Dockerfile 'some\path\Dockerfile' is invalid.
```

Thank you in advance !